# Can bacteria only thrive in agar solution?

Tags: bacteriology

In petri dish, agar is most commonly used for culturing bacteria. So is there any other easily obtainable food sources for culturing bacteria.

Comment: This is the third question you have asked in a short space of time without showing any evidence of having made an effort to find an answer yourself. I have voted to close on this basis.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some misconceptions about growing bacteria. These are cultivated using specific media, for *E.coli* this is usually LB Medium which contains the following ingredients per liter:

- 10g Bacto-tryptone
- 5g yeast extract
- 10g NaCl

This is dissolved in water and subsequently sterilized by autoclaving. Note that there are much more medium recipes for different strains and different culturing conditions.

Bacteria can then be grown either in suspension (shaking in an Erlenmeyer bottle in the liquid media) or on the surface of plates. To produce these plates, you need an agent, which solidifies the medium without having any effect on the growth of the bacteria or the medium. And this is where the Agarose is used. It can be heated up with the medium during sterilization, does not interact with the medium and bacteria do not metabolize it. If you cultivate bacteria, which produce agarase (which is an enzyme to break down agarose), you need to use a different agent to solidify your medium. And you will use a different medium anyways.
They simply grow on the surface of the solified medium and can easily be picked for further analysis or the inoculation of (bigger) liquid cultures.

Answer (score 1):

Gelling agents from natural sources: agar, carrageenan potassium salt, Eladium, gelatin, gellan gum, guar gum.

Agar is not always just a gelling agent. About 100 marine bacterial species are known to utilize agarose; these bacteria produce agarase, an extracellular enzyme that degrades (liquefies) agarose; for example, *Aliagarivorans marinus*, *Aliagarivorans taiwanensis*, *Algibacter agarilyticus*, *Algibacter agarivorans*, *Alterococcus agarolyticus*, *Aquimarina agarilytica*, *Aquimarina agarivorans*.

Comment: Given the origin of agarose from algae, this is not a surprise to find this enzyme in marine bacteria.